# MVC + EF: Problem creating entity with related property by dropdown selection

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Problem:

I cannot create and entity and save it to database. The entity represents a customer that has got personal_data entity (composition), this last one has got and address also in composition, and address has got a region as relation with existing entities.

Model and code:

Model:

```
[Table("customers")]
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string comments { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonalData personal_data { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

[Table("personal_datas")]
public class PersonalData
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Address address { get; set; }
}

[Table("addresses")]
public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string address1 { get; set; }

    ...

    public int region_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("region_id")]
    public virtual Region region { get; set; }
}

[Table("regions")]
public class Region
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("Nombre")]
    public string name { get; set; }        

    public virtual Country country { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.comments = "XXX";
        customer.personal_data = new PersonalData();
        customer.personal_data.last_name_1 = "";
        customer.personal_data.last_name_2 = "";
        customer.personal_data.address = new Address();
        customer.personal_data.address.address1 = "";
        customer.personal_data.address.cp = "";
        customer.personal_data.address.city = "";
        customer.personal_data.address.region_id = 0;

        db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.Entry(customer.personal_data).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.Entry(customer.personal_data.address).State = EntityState.Added;

        db.SaveChanges();
```

Error:

'An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.'

The point is that this work in edit action on the controllers:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,comments,personal_data")] Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(customer.personal_data).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(customer.personal_data.address).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = customer.ID });
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

Any ideas???

**Edit**

I've added "Addresses" to "Regions":

```
public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

And then in "OnModelCreating" I've put this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
        .HasRequired<Region>(s => s.region)
        .WithMany(g => g.Addresses)
        .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.region_id);
```

The error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the foreign key to the database context so EF can satisfy it on creation.  I don't know your database layout but in the context it would look something like the below for a one to many relationship

[this link should be helpful with setup as well](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>(entity =>
        {
            ...removed other configuration for brevity

            entity.HasOne(d => d.MyOtherModel)
                .WithMany(p => p.MyModel)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MyModelKey)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_My_Foreign_Key_Name");
        });
```

Comment: I put this and it does not works: modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired<Region>(s => s.region)
            .WithMany();

Comment: i don't think the .HasRequired method defines a relationship between the entities.  you probably need to use something like .hasone() .withone().  if you have a 1 to 1 relationship.  otherwise you can use the hasmany() withmany() methods to tell EF how to relate the entities to each other